# Loop through array of object and display the values of a prop inside a html tag-Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and I'm trying out an exercise.
I want to loop through an array of objects inside an object and map the index values from one object to the id values inside another object and based on that, I want to perform some operation.
my object:

```
        obj= {
          "text": [{
          "id": 0,
          "name": "aaa"
          },{
          "id": 1,
          "name": "bbb"
          },{
           "id": 3,
          "name": "ccc"
          },{
          "id": 4,
          "name": "ddd"
          }],
  "content": [
      {
      "id": 123,
      "index": 0
      },{
       "id": 1232,
      "index": 2
      },{
       "id": 12333,
      "index": 3
      }
      ]
        }
```

there are 2 parts to this section, 
1) To render the values of the `name` property inside the  `text` object in the form:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
```

2) I want to add a `-` after every group of name values depending on the index provided inside the `content` object.basically I want to map the index values from content object to the id values inside the text object and depending on them , I'd like to add `-` after the name values.
i.e: In above case the indexes are: 0,2,3. hence o/p will look like:

```
aaa
bbb
-
ccc
-
ddd
```

here is the code I have so far for part1:

```
function string () {
var arr = obj.text;
      var output = '';
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        output += '<div>'+ arr[i].text + '</div>';  
    }
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML =  output;
};
```

I need some help on part 2.any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to me a simple problem, so here is a solution, I just wonder if I did not miss a subtlety of the question ?

```js
const
  obj = { text:   [ { id: 0, name: "aaa" } 
                  , { id: 1, name: "bbb" } 
                  , { id: 3, name: "ccc" } 
                  , { id: 4, name: "ddd" } 
                  ] 
        , content:[ { id: 123,   index: 0 } 
                  , { id: 1232,  index: 2 } 
                  , { id: 12333, index: 3 } 
                  ] 
        } 

function string()
  {
  let a_text    = obj.text
    , a_content = obj.content
    , Container = document.getElementById("container")
    , c_Index   = 0

  if ( a_content[c_Index].index === 0 ) c_Index++
  
  for(let i=0; i<a_text.length; i++)
    {
    if (i >= a_content[c_Index].index)
      {
      c_Index++
      let barDiv = document.createElement('div')
      barDiv.textContent = '-'
      Container.appendChild(barDiv)
      }

    let NewDiv = document.createElement('div')
    NewDiv.textContent = a_text[i].name
    Container.appendChild(NewDiv)
    }
  }

string()
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```